# Issues with ion-badge in chrome browser

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to Ionic app development and I have been following tutorials for the same.
I am trying to dynamically assign a color to `<ion-badge>` but it is not working.

So, in my `.html` file, I have the following

```
<ion-col width-20>
    <ion-badge [class]="getWinOrLossBageClass(game)">{{getWinOrLoss(game)}}</ion-badge>
</ion-col>
```

And in my `.ts` file

```
  getWinOrLossBageClass(game) { 
    return game.scoreDisplay.indexOf('W') === 0 ? 'badge-color-primary' : 'badge-color-danger';
  }
```

The badges the showing the texts but not showing the colors.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First**, did you style for these classes `badge-color-primary`, `badge-color-danger`? Because they are not Ionic badge default class.
**Second**, an Ionic badge always have two default class `badge` and `badge-ios` or `badge-md`. So if you set class like `[class]=""`, you will overwrite all these classes and the badge will not work
**Finally**, if you just want to change ion-badge color dynamically, you can do like that:
**Method 1:** Change color propertive (recommend).

```
<ion-badge color="{{getWinOrLossColor(game)}}"></ion-badge>
getWinOrLossColor(game) { 
    return game.scoreDisplay.indexOf('W') === 0 ? 'primary' : 'danger';
}
```

**Methood 2 :** Change the class like you do, but by other way (not recommend):

```
<ion-badge [ngClass]="{'badge-ios-primary':game.scoreDisplay.indexOf('W') === 0, 'badge-ios-danger':game.scoreDisplay.indexOf('W') != 0}"></ion-badge>
```

Answer (score 0):

As the result is coming from your another source, your .ts file, you might need to use the async pipe to wait for the result, to choose the color.

```
<ion-col width-20>
    <ion-badge [class]="getWinOrLossBageClass(game)**|async**">
{{getWinOrLoss(game)}}</ion-badge>
</ion-col>
```

I use the following where the IsOnline is an Observable in my .ts file, and then I set the color of the badge in the HTML when this code returns.

```
<ion-badge [color]="(IsOnline|async)?'secondary':'danger'">
```